# SmsManager MMS APIs on HTC/LG

Tags: android, mms, smsmanager, android-mms, htc-android

I'm using the new `Android` lollipop APIs for sending and receiving MMS messages: [`SmsManager.downloadMultimediaMessage`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#downloadMultimediaMessage(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) and [`SmsManager.sendMultimediaMessage`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendMultimediaMessage(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

This works well on Nexus 4 and 5, but not working at all on HTC One & LG G3 running lollipop.

Looking at the logs on the HTC device, this looks like a worrying error log:

```
MmsServiceBroker "Failed to bind to MmsService"
```

Has anyone managed to get the new MMS APIs working across devices? 
If not, any workaround?

**EDIT:** added LG G3 to the unsupported devices as reported by users

Comment: Which HTC One are you using? One M7, M8, or M9?

Comment: It's an M7 running Lollipop 5.0