# Android: Issue in sending MMS with SmsManager programmatically

Tags: android, mms, telephonymanager, smsmanager, android-mms

I need to send MMS programmatically for which Android has provided support from Lollipop:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendMultimediaMessage(android.content.Context, android.net.Uri, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle, android.app.PendingIntent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendMultimediaMessage(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

I have found this SO link for the same issue:

[Unable to send MMS using SmsManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862925/unable-to-send-mms-using-smsmanager)

Below are issues with MMS API:

- It is not clear how to build message PDU to send.
- Where to mention destination address?
- What is config-overrides?

I searched for PDU message format for MMS but no success.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks