# Sending MMS messages programmatically

Tags: android, telephony, mms, smsmanager, android-mms

I looked at code here: [How to send image via MMS in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/how-to-send-image-via-mms-in-android/2973016#2973016)

And here: [Unable to send MMS using SmsManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862925/unable-to-send-mms-using-smsmanager)

And I did some research from other places as well, but so far I'm quite confused about how to send MMS messages to people without using intents.

If I go to the Android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html), in Telephony there is the SMSManager class. In API Level 21, they added a function called "sendMultimediaMessage()" that sends an MMS message.

```
void sendMultimediaMessage (Context context, 
                Uri contentUri, 
                String locationUrl, 
                Bundle configOverrides, 
                PendingIntent sentIntent)

Parameters
context Context: application context
contentUri  Uri: the content Uri from which the message pdu will be read
locationUrl String: the optional location url where message should be sent to
configOverrides Bundle: the carrier-specific messaging configuration values to override for sending the message.
sentIntent  PendingIntent: if not NULL this PendingIntent is broadcast when the message is successfully sent, or failed"
```

I can't seem to find any real usage or examples of this code being used. In my application, I want  to send a picture message to someone in the background--no application should open in this process (which is why I can't use an intent).

For sending an MMS, I have a few basic questions:

1) How can I take a simple phone number and convert it into an appropriate "address" that MMS can use?

2) How can I actually use this function if all I have is a file path to my image and a phone number to send it to?

I am very new to this, so if someone can provide a thorough explanation I would be very grateful.